# flutter how to push Divider till title property of ListTile dynamically

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to push `Divider` until title property of `ListTile`.
How can I achieve this kind of layout?
There is a circle avatar in leading property.

[image]

Comment: Try giving padding to ListTile to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share any code, I would like to give you a hint of hierarchy (This can't be done using normal `ListTile`, you have to create your own tree widget)

```
Row
  Image // profile pic
  Column
    Row 
      Text // +1 312
      Expanded // empty space
      Text // 09:50
    Row
      Image // Thumbs up image
      Expanded // empty space
      Text // 2
    Divider
```

Comment: I updated image could you check that? What I want is that. Can I achieve by your suggestion?